# IOS Stack View - Multiple Horizontal TextFields

Tags: ios, uitextfield, uistackview

I can't for the life of me get a simple 4 column textfield view created in IB.

I need a layout that looks like this but can't get stack views to space the editfields across the screen for every size device. I've created a constraint for the toolbar to the top/left/right and height.  Then created a stack for the Regular label, then created a stack for the 1x, 1.5x, 2x and 3x, however I can't get them to fill the width of the screen so that they do so for all devices.  After selecting each of the TextFields and adding them to a stack, and then selecting fill, they just disappear?

[image: IB Layout]

Comment: Did you add constraints between the stack view and the edge of the screen?

Comment: Yep, set the constraints to hug the left and right edges.  Then if you look at the size inspector of the stack its 194 and grayed out (which looks like it might be the sum of the 4 textfields width - which also are grayed out if you select any of them).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so @dan got me thinking about the constraints.  I ended up recreating a stack for each row, setting the distribution to equal and then setting the left and right constraint of the parent stack.  (also added 15 spacing and used equal spacing to give it more room).  The control works, however wondering if this is the best way to present this view.  (also getting numerous "Frame will be different at run time" warnings.